# How to run the same unittest suite with several backends

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a JSON parser library ([ijson](https://github.com/isagalaev/ijson)) with a test suite using unittest. The library actually has several parsing implementations — "backends" — in the form of a modules with the identical API. I want to automatically run the test suite several times for each available backend. My goals are:

- I want to keep all tests in one place as they are backend agnostic.
- I want the name of the currently used backend to be visible in some fashion when a test fails.
- I want to be able to run a single TestCase or a single test, as unittest normally allows.

So what's the best way to organize the test suite for this? Write a custom test runner? Let TestCases load backends themselves? Imperatively generate separate TestCase classes for each backend?

By the way, I'm not married to unittest library in particular and I'm open to try another one if it solves the problem. But unittest is preferable since I already have the test code in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common way is to group all your tests together in one class with an abstract method that creates an instance of the backend (if you need to create multiple instances in a test), or expects `setUp` to create an instance of the backend.

You can then create subclasses that create the different backends as needed.

If you are using a test loader that automatically detects `TestCase` subclasses, you'll probably need to make one change: don't make the common base class a subclass of `TestCase`: instead treat it as a mixin, and make the backend classes subclass from both `TestCase` and the mixin.

For example:

```
class BackendTests:
    def make_backend(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def test_one(self):
        backend = self.make_backend()
        # perform a test on the backend

class FooBackendTests(unittest.TestCase, BackendTests):
    def make_backend(self):
        # Create an instance of the "foo" backend:
        return foo_backend

class BarBackendTests(unittest.TestCase, BackendTests):
    def make_backend(self):
        # Create an instance of the "bar" backend:
        return bar_backend
```

When building a test suite from the above, you will have independent test cases `FooBackendTests.test_one` and `BarBackendTests.test_one` that test the same feature on the two backends.

Comment: But it won't help me to actually run each test several times for each backend? If I'm not missing anything I will have to manually write a "for" loop in each test method to go through backends.

Comment: Oh, sorry, disregard that, I just re-read your answer more carefully. I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: There is no need for a for loop, right.  The backend test case classes inherit their own copy of each generic test.

Comment: Thanks for the code example. BTW a simpler way is to have a backend as a class attribute instead of returning it from a method.

Comment: If a class attribute is enough for your use case, then go ahead -- the simplest solution that works is often the best.  I used a method in the example since sometimes it takes a bit more effort to set up a backend for testing (e.g. they might need access to a temporary directory or other resource that needs cleaning up).

Answer (score 1):

I took James Henstridge's idea with a mixin class holding all the tests but actual test cases are then generated imperatively, as backends may fail on import in which case we don't want to test them:

```
class BackendTests(object):
    def test_something(self):
        # using self.backend 

# Generating real TestCase classes for each importable backend
for name in ['backend1', 'backend2', 'backend3']:
    try:
        classname = '%sTest' % name.capitalize()
        locals()[classname] = type(
            classname,
            (unittest.TestCase, BackendTests),
            {'backend': import_module('backends.%s' % name)},
        )
    except ImportError:
        pass
```